# Facebook OAuth Get Business Manager Id

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-ads-api

I am struggling to get the business manager id, via facebook oauth of business manager account.I also have standard access api

```
Api::init(APP_ID, APP_SECRET, $access_token);
$fbUser = new Business('me');
$business_manager = $fbUser->read();
```

The above code don't return the business id.

Can anyone tell me how to fetch the business id??

Thanks,
Ronak Shah

Answer (score 0):

The list of Businesses a user has access to can be retrieved by calling `/<API VERSION>/<USER ID>/businesses`

This endpoint is currently documented here:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/businessmanager#read

With the reference doc here: 
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/businesses/

Comment: Yes this works fine,but I notice one thing that the graph api response also returns the paging next parameter and executing that returns blank data.Any idea why so?

Comment: It may be the last page of results? https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api#paging